# Why does xscreensaver get removed for each Ubuntu version upgrade?

Tags: xscreensaver

This is less a technical question, and more seeking the reasoning (which may end up being technical anyways).

I use xscreensaver because I like the screensavers, and lock my computer regularly. However, every time I do a version upgrade to my Ubuntu install, it always removes xscreensaver in the process, and I need to reinstall it afterwards.

Not that big of a deal, but this seems to be the only package that is treated like this, and I don't understand why.

Does anyone have an idea of this? It's kind of confusing.

Comment: Can you be more specific about exactly which versions you upgraded to when this happened?

Comment: Every version for the last 3-4 years. I'm not exaggerating.

Comment: Without specific logs showing which packages are being removed and installed, it's not going to be particularly to answer this accurately. However, it's almost certainly because something in the dependency tree causes the chain to break, which necessitates removal. This is even more likely if you install things from PPAs.

Comment: So 14.04, 14.10, 15.04, 15.10, 16.04, 16.10, 17.04, 17.10...approximately?

Comment: Yes. 10char10char